# Blazor Movement when mouse over?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, blazor

I have some ui inside a flex container, that doesn’t align correctly vertically, align content needs to have a set height but I want it to be auto but that’s a another question. I want to animate the cards inside the flex box, but I’m using blazor and can’t get the components. Is there a way to do something like [this](https://css-tricks.com/animate-a-container-on-mouse-over-using-perspective-and-transform/). I don’t really know JavaScript but I do know c# pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of JavaScript DOM events are still not supported directly in Blazor.  I assume that they are working toward that, but you may need to wire up some JavaScript interop to catch some events.

Comment: I’ve never done js interop, I thought that would be the answer but how would you get all of the cards, do you have an example that you could show me? Thanks!